# No se insertan los datos en mi tabla SQLite usando Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, kotlin, sqlite

Estoy creando una aplicacion básica en Android Studio utilizando SQLite, he creado una base de datos y 4 tablas, en las dos primeras puedo guardar, modificar y eliminar sin problema, pero en las dos últimas no puedo guardar datos. He seguido el mismo patron de código para insertar los datos que use en las dos primeras, y al ejecutarlo me dice que los datos fueron guardados, pero no se guardan en mi tabla, ¿Cómo podria resolver esto?

Este es mi codigo de SQLite, con este codigo estoy creando las tablas dentro de la base de datos y las tablas se crean correctamente:

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
    import android.util.Log
    
class SQLite(context: Context?, name: String?, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version: Int) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, factory, version) {

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "HomeCare"
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
    }
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        db?.execSQL("create table register(id_register integer primary key, fullname text, username text, password text, position text)")
        Log.i("MyLog","create table register")
        db?.execSQL("create table addProfile(id_profile integer primary key, fullname text, birthday date, address text, phone int, email text, availability text, position text)")
        Log.i("MyLog","create table add profile")
        db?.execSQL("create table assignCall(id_call integer primary key, clientName text, birthday date, address text, careName text, care2Name text, dateCall date, startCall text, finishCall text, statusCall text)")
        Log.i("MyLog","create table assign call")
        db?.execSQL("create table Calls(id_call integer primary key, fullname text, address text, careName text, dateCall date, timeCall text)")

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

    }
}
```

Este es mi código insert, cuando corro mi aplicacion, aparentemente la funcion de insert esta correindo correctamente porque me indica que se ha guardado correctamente, pero en realidad no se estan guardando los datos en la tabla:

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

class AssignCallActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //Declare variables
    var clientNameField:EditText?=null
    var birthdayField: EditText?=null
    var addressField: EditText?=null
    var careNameField: EditText?=null
    var care2NameField: EditText?=null
    var dateCallField: EditText?=null
    var startCallField: EditText?=null
    var finishCallField : EditText?=null
    lateinit var statusSpinner:Spinner
    private lateinit var assignButton:Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assign_call)

        val assignCallTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_assign_call)
        val homeCareTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_HomeCareP)
        val backButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.id_back_button_assign)

        clientNameField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id_client_name_assign)
        birthdayField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id_birthday_assign)
        addressField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id_address_assign)
        careNameField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id_care_name_assign)
        care2NameField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id_care2_name_assign)
        dateCallField = findViewById(R.id.id_date_call_assign)
        startCallField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id_start_call_assign)
        finishCallField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.id_finish_call_assign)
        statusSpinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner_status_call_assign)
        assignButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_assign_call)

        backButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MaintenanceCallsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        Log.i("MyLog","start of back button")

        // Create an array with the options
        val options = arrayOf("Active", "Cancel")
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, options)

        // Apply the design of the spinner
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

        // Allocates the adapter al spinner
        statusSpinner.adapter = adapter
        Log.i("MyLog","array option")
    }

    fun insert(view:View){
        var dbHelper = SQLite(this,"HomeCare",null,1)
        var db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
        Log.i("MyLog","db writableDatabase")

        var clientName= clientNameField?.text.toString()
        var birthday= birthdayField?.text.toString()
        var address= addressField?.text.toString()
        var careName= careNameField?.text.toString()
        var care2Name= care2NameField?.text.toString()
        var dateCall = dateCallField?.text.toString()
        var startCall= startCallField?.text.toString()
        var finishCall= finishCallField?.text.toString()
        var status=statusSpinner?.selectedItem.toString()
        Log.i("MyLog","passing the data entered")


        if(clientName.isEmpty()==false &&
                birthday.isEmpty()==false &&
                address.isEmpty()==false &&
                careName.isEmpty()==false &&
                care2Name.isEmpty()==false &&
                dateCall.isEmpty()==false &&
                startCall.isEmpty()==false &&
                finishCall.isEmpty()==false &&
                status.isEmpty()==false){

            var callSave = ContentValues()
            callSave.put("clientName", clientName)
            callSave.put("birthday", birthday)
            callSave.put("address",address)
            callSave.put("careName",careName)
            callSave.put("care2Name",care2Name)
            callSave.put("dateCall",dateCall)
            callSave.put("startCall",startCall)
            callSave.put("finishCall",finishCall)
            callSave.put("status",status)

            db.insert("assignCall",null,callSave)
            Log.i("MyLog","saved data")

            clientNameField?.setText("")
            birthdayField?.setText("")
            addressField?.setText("")
            careNameField?.setText("")
            care2NameField?.setText("")
            dateCallField?.setText("")
            startCallField?.setText("")
            finishCallField?.setText("")
            statusSpinner?.setSelection(0)
            Log.i("MyLog","cleaned data")

            Toast.makeText(this, "Successful call assigned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out all of the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    fun addTestRecord(view: View) {
        // Add test record data
        val testClientName = "John Doe"
        val testBirthday = "1990-01-01"
        val testAddress = "123 Test St"
        val testCareName = "Test Care 1"
        val testCare2Name = "Test Care 2"
        val testDateCall = "2023-07-24"
        val testStartCall = "10:00 AM"
        val testFinishCall = "12:00 PM"
        val testStatus = "Active"

        var con = SQLite(this, "HomeCare", null, 1)
        var db = con.writableDatabase

        var callSave = ContentValues()
        callSave.put("clientName", testClientName)
        callSave.put("birthday", testBirthday)
        callSave.put("address", testAddress)
        callSave.put("careName", testCareName)
        callSave.put("care2Name", testCare2Name)
        callSave.put("dateCall", testDateCall)
        callSave.put("startCall", testStartCall)
        callSave.put("finishCall", testFinishCall)
        callSave.put("status", testStatus)

        db.insert("assignCall", null, callSave)

        Toast.makeText(this, "Test record added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```